# Is this matrix class thread safe when writing on different indices?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, boost

As you may notice there is a double* storage behind this. Any value read/written is translated into a flat index so it is stored in a large single dimentional array.

I need to know whether i can write on different indices in an object of this type in different threads? I am using the operator () to set the values. The bounds are predefined when intantiating the object. i.e: Matrix m(rows,cols);
I am using this in boost threads and having issues. Do i need to put any scoped locks? but that would be a performance cost i believe.

```
class matrix
{
public:
    matrix(size_t rows, size_t cols):_rows(rows),_cols(cols),_data(0)
    {
        reset(rows,  cols);
    }
    matrix():_data(0),_rows(0),_cols(0){}
    ~matrix()
    {
        if (0 != _data)
        {
            delete [] _data;
        }
    }

    matrix(const matrix& copythis)
        :_data(0),_rows(0),_cols(0)
    {
        if (0 != _data)
        {
            delete [] _data;
        }
        _rows = copythis.rows();
        _cols = copythis.cols();
        _data = new double [_rows * _cols];

        if (0 == _data)
        {
            NL_THROW("Insufficient memory to create a cloned matrix of double of " << _rows << " X " << _cols);
        }

        memcpy(_data, copythis._data, _rows * _cols * sizeof(double) );

    }


public:

    const matrix& operator = (const matrix& copythis)
    {
        if (0 != _data)
        {
            delete [] _data;
        }
        _rows = copythis.rows();
        _cols = copythis.cols();
        _data = new double [_rows * _cols];

        if (0 == _data)
        {
            NL_THROW("Insufficient memory to create a cloned matrix of double of " << _rows << " X " << _cols);
        }

        memcpy(_data, copythis._data, _rows * _cols * sizeof(double) );

        return (*this);

    }







    double* cArray()
    {
        if (0 == _data)
        {
            NL_THROW("Matrix is not initialised");
        }
        return _data;
    }



    void reset(size_t rows, size_t cols)
    {
        if (0 != _data)
        {
            delete [] _data;
        }
        _rows = rows;
        _cols = cols;
        _data = new double[rows * cols];

        if (0 == _data)
        {
            NL_THROW("Insufficient memory to create a matrix of double of " << _rows << " X " << _cols);
        }
        memset(_data, 0, sizeof(double) * _rows * _cols);
    }





    double& operator () (size_t rowIndex, size_t colIndex) const
    {
        if (rowIndex >= _rows)
        {
            NL_THROW("Row index " << rowIndex << " out of range(" << _rows - 1 << ")");
        }

        if (colIndex >= _cols)
        {
            NL_THROW("Column index " << colIndex << " out of range(" << _cols - 1 << ")");
        }

        size_t flatIndex = colIndex + rowIndex * _cols;
        return _data[flatIndex];

    }


    Array rowSlice(size_t rowIndex) const
    {
        if (rowIndex >= _rows)
        {
            NL_THROW("Cannot slice matrix, required row: " << rowIndex << " is out of range(" << (_rows - 1) << ")");
        }
        Array retval(_data + rowIndex * _cols, _cols);

        /*
        for(size_t i = 0; i < _cols; i++)
        {
            retval[i] = operator()(rowIndex, i);
        }
        */
        return retval;
    }



    Array colSlice(size_t colIndex) const
    {
        if (colIndex >= _cols)
        {
            NL_THROW("Cannot slice matrix, required row: " << colIndex << " is out of range(" << (_cols - 1) << ")");
        }
        Array retval(_rows);
        for(size_t i = 0; i < _rows; i++)
        {
            retval[i] = operator()(i, colIndex);
        }
        return retval;
    }


    void fill(double value)
    {
        for(size_t rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < _rows; rowIndex++)
        {
            for(size_t colIndex = 0; colIndex < _cols; colIndex++)
            {
                size_t flatIndex = colIndex + rowIndex * _cols;
                _data[flatIndex] = value;
            }
        }
    }


    bool isEmpty() const
    {
        if (0 == _rows) return true;
        if (0 == _cols) return true;
        return false;
    }

    size_t rows() const {return _rows;}
    size_t cols() const {return _cols;}

private:
    double* _data;
    size_t _rows;
    size_t _cols;
};
```

Comment: looks like the problem is elsewhere (what are you *really* doing in all the threads). you can start by using std::atomic (double is not atomic on 32bit platform), or use std::mutex for any access (for any "transaction" - work with the matrix)

Comment: i will try lock but i am worried about the performance overhead. btw i am on 64-bit

Comment: btw i have objects which contain instances of this matrix and those objects and their matrix members are being initialised and wriiten in multiple threads

Comment: 1. Are you sure that you are not accessing the matrix (from some thread) BEFORE it was constructed? 2. Are you sure you trully only write? (or do you read as well?) 3. Are the cells (and possible value computation) related or independent?

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that all your threads *never* collide on the same element of the matrix, then you won't need locking. In practice it's not realistic to expect such a guarantee, so you'll need locking.

Comment: ok, so where do i put the lock ? in the operator ? as the operator is just returning the reference. does that apply for setting the value to that reference as well ?

Comment: The lock granularity is your choice - the whole matrix, a number of rows, a single row, or even a lock per element. Ans yes, it'll affect performance, the bigger the locked area per one lock, the worse it will perform. Actually, all will depend on clients of your `matrix` class.

Comment: I need to know where in this class i put the lock/unlock please ?

Comment: If the licensing is acceptable ( https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/licensing ), just use Intel's implementation ( https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506203 ).

Comment: I cant find any matrix implementation in Intel TBB. Do i need to implement using concurrent vector you mean ?

Comment: If you are trying to build something big then it might make sense to use an already existing linear algebra package - for example Eigen (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org). It supports MT-safe matrices

Comment: If you just need to grab MT programming using matrices as examples, then look for coding samples with the Boost `mutex` class

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about making a `std::vector`-like thread safe container.  You might be able to pull it off by using TBB as a building block, but to be honest, I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The way this class is written, you need locks on **every** method except the getters `rows()` and `cols()`, pretty much at the broadest possible scope on each of those methods.

You can't even rely on the `size_t` type being atomic from saving you any locks, because `reset()` sets both `_row` and `_col`  non-atomically.  Any operation that needs to know about `_row` and `_col`, e.g. `isEmpty()`,  will run into trouble if `reset()` is called from another thread.

Comment: Is it only about the reset ? What if i am not calling it inside a thread, however it is only called once inside the constructor only. But that is for an instance newly being created so should not be a problem ?